# uiscrollview not scrolling inspite of providing delegates

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have uiscrollview containing 3 uitextfields, 1 uitextview and 1uibutton.
The content size of the uiscrollview is more than the frame size of uiscrollview.
Even i have applied the delegate as self programmatically then too uiscrollview doesn't scroll.
Tired searching a lot from last 2 weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the answer it was the tick mark on the Use AutoLayout check box in the File Inspector which needs to be removed.

Selecting AutoLayout doesn't allow the uiscrollview to perform scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it has `userInteractionEnabled = YES`, check its `scrollEnabled` property as well. Assigning of not assigning delegates won't make a difference to the scrollview's ability to scroll or not.

You could also try manually setting the `contentOffset` of a scrollview to narrow down the area where the problem is.